# KSQL streams - Iterate over a JSON

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

How to Iterate over a JSON in KSQL streams:

My JSON looks like:

```
{
   "Obj" {
       "ID" : "1"
    },
    "KeyValues": {
        "Key1": "value1",
        "Key2": "value2",
        "Key3": "value3",
        "Key4": "value4",
        "Key5": "value5",
        "Key6": "value6",
        "Key7": "value7",
        "Key8": "value8",
        "Key9": "value9",
        "Key10": "value10",
            |
            |
            |
            |

        "KeyN": "valueN"
  }
}
```

How can I get below o/p in KSQL . Need to iterate over JSON object for N elements and list as below.

```
   ID    KEY              VALUE
----------------------------------    
   1     Key1            value1
   1     Key2            value2
   1     Key3            value3
   1     Key4            value4
   1     Key5            value5
   1     Key6            value6
   1     Key7            value7
   1     Key8            value8
   1     Key9            value9
   1     Key10           value10
   1            |
   1            |
   1            |
   1            |
   1 
   1      KeyN          valueN
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `KeyValues` be an array, if it's "N" length?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt It's not an array. Generally it is supposed to be array, But this requirement is falling as above JSON i.e an JOSN object without Array.

Comment: I too have exactly same scenario like this. And it's not an array. Any way is it possible in ksql?

Comment: What exactly do you need to do when iterating? Maybe you could write a UDF?

Comment: @cricket_007 After iterating , we need to push those data to SQL server from a connector. I am not aware of UDF, Could you please give me a link to refer.

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/udf.html#implement-a-custom-function

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a [UDTF](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/table-functions/) is the right solution for you. You can see [explode](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/ksql-engine/src/main/java/io/confluent/ksql/function/udtf/array/Explode.java) as an example of a UDTF that takes in an array and then outputs N rows, one for each element.

The signature for your UDTF would be similar:

```java
@Udtf(schema = "STRUCT<key VARCHAR, value VARCHAR>")
public <T> List<Struct> expandMapEntries(final Map<String, String> input) {
  // output a list of key value pairs as a struct from 'input'
}
```

Then you can use this UDTF and select the fields from it (something like the below):

```sql
CREATE STREAM expanded AS SELECT EXPAND_MAP_ENTRIES(KeyValues) AS keyVals FROM source;
CREATE STREAM flattened AS keyVals->key as `KEY`, keyVals->value AS VALUE FROM expanded;
```

Let me know if that works for you, and feel free to reach out on the community slack (@almog) - I'm quite interested in this use case.